# How to debug Qt executable when use CMake + MSVC?

Tags: cmake

I create usual hello-world Qt executable via cmake+msvc.

But I cant launch or debug it - the launсh fails by the reason of the absence needed Qt dll.

I found that if I add the

```
D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\bin;
D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\plugins\platforms;
```

to the PATH environment variable - the issue gone.

But I dont want that paths in the global environment variables (I plan to have few different versions of the Qt libraries, so all time switching global environment variables will be unusable).

How I could pass the paths to Qt librariles to the cmake for debug/launch executable without modifying the global environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the path to your local debugging environment to your CMake generated Visual Studio Solution, either by adding it in the GUI under Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Environment

[image]

or (since CMake 3.13.0) in your CMakeLists.txt by setting the appropriate property on the target.

```
set_target_properties(exe_target PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\bin;D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\plugins\platforms")
```

Although these properties are prefixed with `VS_DEBUGGER_` they apply to both the Debug and Release versions.

Other `VS_DEBUGGER_` properties might be of interest too.

See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/search.html?q=VS_DEBUGGER_) for documentation.

Comment: Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Environment is absent on cmake project, it appears when used .sln files. VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT and other doesnt take affect with latest msvc and latest cmake. I saw this solutions but them both dont works

Comment: *Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Environment is absent on cmake project* this is not what I meant: You should generate the VS solution, open it and add the setting manually. I use both given solutions every day. Do you mean how to start your Qt executables from a command line without changing the global paths? Then set the PATH variable in the console window `set PATH=D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\bin;D:\libs\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\plugins\platforms;%PATH%` it changes the local environment of the console window but not the global setting.

Comment: I get you point of view. Yes, it would works. But I try to find solution for new suggested way. The msvs team suggets to use cmake with msvs in the way of "Open folder" menu. In this case we dont need to generate anything - all do msvc by self. It works very fine except with qt - with qt I cant debug code. I found only one semisolution - to fix launch.vs.json - It helps for some dll, but not for all :(

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution.

open Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > add new location.

the location is your qt MSVC bin floder, in my case is "D:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\bin".

don't forget select new location, now you can use vs debug qt exe.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. Tried but no luck.